# Parse JSON returned from Google timezone API

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am trying to perform the simple task of using Google's timezone API to look up the timezone of given coordinates. I am then trying to parse the returned JSON just to show the time zone itself. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here? Any help would be great! Thank you!

```
<?php

$jsonObject = file_get_contents("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json?    
timestamp=0&sensor=true&location=39.6034810,-119.6822510");

foreach($jsonObject as $p)
{
    echo "$p[timeZoneId]";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 4):

`file_get_contents` returns a string:

```
$object = json_decode($jsonObject);
echo $object->timeZoneId;
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to decode the json object. It's just a string right now, which foreach won't work on. (only arrays or objects).

```
<?php

$jsonObject = file_get_contents("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json?    
timestamp=0&sensor=true&location=39.6034810,-119.6822510");

$jsonObject = json_decode($jsonObject);

foreach($jsonObject as $p)
{
    echo "$p is $jsonObject[$p]";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse the response from Google (which is really just text in the JSON format) into a PHP array. Use something like this:

```
$json_text = file_get_contents(...);
$obj = json_decode($json_text, true);
foreach ($obj as $p)
{
    echo "$p[timeZoneId]";
}
```

I think you'll want to pass `true` to `json_decode` so the result is transformed into an easy-to-use associative array. Read [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) for more information. Good luck.